# Does MSVC 2017 support AVX 512 with auto-vectorization?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, avx512

I keep reading about AVX 512 with MSVC 2017, but the maximum target in the settings is /arch:AVX2. I tried /arch:AVX512 and tried stopping it in various places (in a benchmark app testing various vectorizable loops) and I could see AVX instructions, but not AVX512 really and I'm running it on a computer, that doesn't support AVX512, so it should crash. So what is the situation? (I'm running MSVC 15.6.6).

Comment: MSVC's AVX512 support is still in an infancy. Even its intrinsics support is so buggy that it's almost unusable. Given them a few more years to fix that, then maybe they'll start looking at auto-vectorization. If you want auto-vectorization with AVX512, use another compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you have experiences with CLANG and this? Generally CLANG generates worse code than MSVC according to my experiments, but if it can do AVX512 and it would actually beneficial, then why the hell not :).

Comment: I don't use Clang so I don't know. But it's worth trying. GCC on Windows is broken for AVX. So the only other option is the Intel Compiler which is excellent for AVX(512) - but isn't free.

Comment: I actually gave up on ICL, I have been using it for years, but the code is just unreliable (plus it's like 4x larger, takes 5x more time to compile and the performance improvement is like 1-2% tops from my tests, that may vary on the application of course)

Comment: The 5x longer to compile is definitely true. So I use it only for production builds and not for development through an IDE - unless I'm doing AVX512 for which I have no choice. The 4x larger is because it's too aggressive with inlining (I spent a lot of time investigating this). That can be overridden with the right compiler options. I can't say much about it being unreliable since all other problems I've had with it are easily worked-around.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the size either, but several times it just generated crashing code. Once I was able to find out what was wrong and they fixed it, but it was a long and painful process and with the problems I had recently there was just no way to find out what was wrong. And really the last thing you want is a compiler, which may generate crashing code at some unknown moment... Not worth the tiny performance improvement imho.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC currently does not support auto-vectorization targeting AVX-512, only up to AVX2.